# Controlling transparency of D3 orthographic projections

Tags: d3.js

I want to use a transparent globe in D3 and can't figure out how to achieve it (i.e. remove the white surface so other side of globe can be seen).  I can colour the surface (which effectively becomes sea after land is drawn), but cannot remove it or make transparent.  Grateful for assistance.

I tried to make the code (adapted from [Bostock's example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/3795040/)) into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/y9db3/) but can't get the topojson to load.  Would be useful if anyone knows how to get that working if its possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 500,
    height = 400;

var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()
    .scale(150)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .clipAngle(90);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

varλ = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, width])
    .range([-180, 180]);

varφ = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, height])
    .range([90, -90]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.on("mousemove", function () {
    var p = d3.mouse(this);
    projection.rotate([λ (p[0]), φ (p[1])]);
    svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
});

d3.json("world-110m.json", function (error, world) {
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land))
        .attr("class", "land")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("stroke", "#000")
        .attr("fill", "none");

});

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the call to [clipAngle](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#clipAngle) on your projection or pass it null instead of 90, and you should get a transparent globe.

Comment: In my case I had a transparent globe but didn't want one... adding `clipAngle(90)` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The white parts of the paths are transparent by default (or rather, there is nothing in the white parts of the globe). However, the far side of the earth is not rendered as part of the path that creates the shape of the visible side.

To create a 'transparent' globe, all you would need to do would be to draw the other side of the globe (using the same projection, but with a reversed scale for the x-dimension) in the same spot as the visible side of the globe. You'll probably want some css in addition to make the other side of the globe lighter (so you can differentiate between the sides).

Comment: Thanks ckersch, but shouldn't the features on the far side be made smaller?  Surely this method will enlarge them as if they're closer to the viewpoint..

Comment: It depends on the distance you make the projection at. The d3 orthographic projection is projected from a distance of infinity, so a full hemisphere is displayed with no perspective changes in size. If you wanted a non-infinite projection distance, you'd have to make a new projection, plus a new projection for the back side of the globe.